# CURDATE() returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql

I've been questioning myself why the `CURDATE()` doesn't work on my SQL query:

```
$sql = $database->get_assoc("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `post_date` = CURDATE()");
echo $sql['title'].' | '.$sql['status'].' | '.$sql['post_date'];
```

It only returns the separator `|`, and the data is not there. However, if I change the `CURDATE()` from the query to its actual date (e.g. `2021-02-08`), it does work. It should print the data as set from the `echo` code above for example:

```
Beep Boop | Scheduled | 2021-02-08
```

I've tried the same query using [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03b8db/6/0) and it shows the data fine. The `post_date` is only set to date, not datetime.

What am I missing / doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

[EDIT]
This has been answered by Shamim.

Comment: try `SELECT CURDATE()` to debug the results. There are a few more issues: do not use `table` as table name, the backtick at `post_date` is not required and don't `SELECT *`

Comment: @Raptor I just use the `table` as an example, it really isn't my table's name. Also, your suggestion will not return anything if I don't select any column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Be sure you have today's date record in your table then

Check `post_date` column datatype or format of your date
**it must be `YYYY-mm-dd`** format

Try this

**Before**

```
$sql = $database->get_assoc("SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `post_date` = CURDATE()");
echo $sql['title'].' | '.$sql['status'].' | '.$sql['post_date'];
```

**After**

```
$sql = $database->get_assoc("SELECT ,DATE(post_date) post_date 
FROM `table` 
WHERE DATE(`post_date`) = CURDATE()");
echo $sql['title'].' | '.$sql['status'].' | '.$sql['post_date'];
```